Hypothesis Test: Fair Die vs. Fair Coin
Exercise:
In an adjacent room, there is a fair coin, whose sides are labeled with $1$ and $2$, and a fair die.
A person takes one of the two objects, makes $100$ throws, and tells you the number $W_{100}$ of throws that resulted in a $1$.
You have to guess whether the coin or the die was used. Test the die ($H_0$) against the coin ($H_1$).
What is the test for ($H_0$) against ($H_1$) with a significance level $\alpha \leq 0.05$ and maximum power?
What is the form of the corresponding acceptance region for ($H_0$)?
You may leave a constant unspecified but should provide an R program that determines the required constant.
My approach yet:
I thought that the exercise wants one to pick the Maximum-Likelihood-Ratio-Test since after the Lemma of Neyman-Pearson it is uniformly most powerful when we have only two simple hypothesis we want to test against each other (which is the case here).
My problem is to yield a suitable condition for $W_{100}$ that I can use to construct the corresponding R-Code which yields me my critical value $c$ for which I reject the null:
My Likelihood-Ratio after rearranging terms looks like:
$$Q=(\frac{1}{3})^{W_{100}} \cdot(\frac{5}{3})^{100-W_{100}}$$
and I want that under the assumption $p=0.5$:
$$\mathbb{P}(Q\geq c)\leq 0.05=\alpha$$
now I do not now the distribution of this $Q$ but solving for $W_{100}$ yields (I assume I made a mistake somewhere here but I am not able to find it):
$$W_{100} \geq \frac{\log(c)-100\log(5/3)}{\log(1/3)-\log(5/3)}$$
and this is binomial distributed to $n=100$ and (assumed) $p=0.5$
As said, I am pretty sure I am not on the right track with this.
May anyone be so kind and help?
